# How to insert script in head of iframe have a src?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

How to insert script in head of iframe?

i have a iframe like this

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://twely.org/do_run/data/11112014/p5zcge3da4/8r1m9hb6v4/index.php"></iframe>
```

how to insert script(see below) in head of above iframe

```
<script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: What is the need of doing this ?

Comment: You should include in head... Also, you can't load `php` files using cross domain

Comment: There's no way, if you [don't have control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) over `http://twely.org/`.